# Inflate custom component into ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I know how to inflate custom layout from XML, but how can I inflate custom component into ArrayAdapter?

Here is my component:

```
public class MyComponent extends LinearLayout
{

    private EditText mText;
    private ImageView mImage;

    public MyComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        View.inflate(context, R.layout.cell_layout, this);
    }

    private void initComponent(){
        mText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lats_field);
        mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flag_img);
    }

    public EditText getText()
    {
        return mText;
    }

    public void setText(EditText mText)
    {
        this.mText = mText;
    }

    public ImageView getImage()
    {
        return mImage;
    }

    public void setImage(ImageView mImage)
    {
        this.mImage = mImage;
    }
}
```

And I would like to add it to ListView using ArrayAdapter. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an xml and put inside it MyComponent:

```
<com.package.MyComponent
     android:layout_with="fill_parent"
     android:layout_heigth="wrap_content"
 />
```

override the getView from your ArrayAdapter and when convertView is null inflate this layout, and assign it to convertView. Otherwise you can define the constructor of LinearLayout that takes only the Context as parameter and, in inside the getView, when convertView is null you do

```
convertView = new MyComponent(mContext);
```